# Visual Studio Code - Stuck in extreme zoom in mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

I love VSC, but my program is stuck in extreme zoom in mode. Zoom out keyboard shortcut doesn't work. I cant navigate through most of the menus to change view. I found view-appearance-zoom out, but it doesn't change anything when I click on it. I really

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code Magnification Setting Reset](https://superuser.com/questions/1428673/visual-studio-code-magnification-setting-reset)

Answer (score 2):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type "reset zoom"
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion. The keyboard shortcut opened the command prompt, bu the words "reset zoom" didn't do anything.