# Visual Studio Code Magnification Setting Reset

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally changed the zoom setting to 12 on the Visual Studio Code Editor, now only a small portion (highly magnified) of the editor is visible; how do I reset it back to default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, try the default hotkey of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad0</kbd> to reset the zoom level. If that doesn't work, then try the following:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the command pallete.
2. Type "reset zoom"
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]